# xml2js Tags inside Tag value

Tags: xml, parsing, tags, nestjs, xml2js

I am trying to parse XML files in nestjs using xml2js an everything worked fine until now, but now i've got a problem:

XML to parse:

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <string name="example_text">
        Hi there MR. <xliff:g id="mister" example="John">%1$s</xliff:g> and Mrs. <xliff:g id="miss" example="Jessica">%1$s</xliff:g>
    </string>
</resources>
```

Usage of xml2js in code:

```
const xmlParser = require('xml2js').Parser({trim: true, ignoreAttrs: false, mergeAttrs: true});
...
const xml = entry.getData().toString('utf8');
          xmlParser.parseString(xml, function(err, result) {
            console.log('Result: ', result);
            if (result && result.resources.string) {
              const strings = result.resources.string;
              strings.map(x => {
                console.log('String: ', x);
              });
            }
          });
```

Output:

```
Result:  { resources:
   { 'xmlns:xliff': [ 'urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2' ],
     string: [ [Object] ] } }
String:  { _: 'Hi there MR.  and Mrs.',
  name: [ 'example_text' ],
  'xliff:g':
   [ { _: '%1$s', id: [Array], example: [Array] },
     { _: '%1$s', id: [Array], example: [Array] } ] }
```

And now my problem:

- I want to know where the xliff Tags are located inside the string "Hi There MR. %1$s and Mrs.%1$s"
- The String does not even include "%1$s" or any information regarding the xliff tags

Why i need the information:

- i want to replace %1$s with something else and store the information included in the xliff

Is there a way to do this with xml2js, or do i need another library to parse the xml, in order to get the needed information?